# Given a single column of effective dates, is there a SQL statement that can transform that into date ranges?

Tags: sql, sqlite, range

Similar to another question I've posted, given the following table...

```
Promo   EffectiveDate
------   -------------
PromoA  1/1/2016
PromoB  4/1/2016
PromoC  7/1/2016
PromoD  10/1/2016
PromoE  1/1/2017
```

What is the easiest way to transform it into start and end dates, like so...

```
Promo   StartDate  EndDate
------  ---------  ---------
PromoA  1/1/2016   4/1/2016
PromoB  4/1/2016   7/1/2016
PromoC  7/1/2016   10/1/2016
PromoD  10/1/2016  1/1/2017
PromoE  1/1/2017   null (ongoing until a new Effective Date is added)
```

### Update

Correlated queries seem to be the simplest solution, but as I understand it, they are extremely inefficient since the subquery has to run once per row of the outer select.

What I was thinking as a potential solution was something along the lines of selecting the values from the table a second time, but eliminating the first result, then pairing them up with the first select by ordinal index with a simple outer left join.

As an example, substituting letters for dates above, the first select would be like A,B,C,D,E and second would be B,C,D,E (which is the first select minus the first record 'A') then pairing them up by ordinal index with a simple outer left join, resulting in A-B, B-C, C-D, D-E, E-null.  However I couldn't figure out the syntax to make that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a correlated query with `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT t.promo,t.effectiveDate as start_date,
       (SELECT s.effectiveDate FROM YourTable s
        WHERE s.date > t.date
        ORDER BY s.effectiveDate
        LIMIT 1) as end_date
FROM YourTable t
```

**EDIT:** Here is a solution with a join :

```
SELECT t.promo,t.effectiveDate as start_date,
       MIN(s.effectiveDate) as end_date
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.date < s.date)
GROUP BY t.promo,t.effectiveDate
```

Comment: This looks promising.  One question though... this seems like that order-by/limit in the middle would be pretty expensive.  Couldn't the same thing be achieved with a simple MIN clause?  (i.e. Min(s.effectiveDate) where s.effectiveDate > t.effectiveDate kinda thing?

Comment: Yes, but there is no promise that this would be faster that what I've suggested. This is not supposed to be expensive at all. @MarqueIV

Comment: @MarqueIV After seeing your update -> No, correlated queries won't necessarily be slower than the alternatives like `JOINs` . They can even be faster some of the times. I'll update my answer and will add a solution with a join.

Comment: @MarqueIV this is the correct answer, or at least the correct style of query for your objective. Your update (where you mention the "base list" joined to the list without the first item) is exactly what the join query above does, but it does it in a way that is optimized for **set-based operations**. If you google that term, you will start to see why that way of thinking is so important for sql developers. The correlated subquery works too. Sometimes its slower, sometimes faster, it depends on your situation, and only **your** testing of both options can decide which one makes more sense.

Comment: @SlimsGhost, in regards to the first solution in this answer, what about my earlier statement that an order-by/limit seems to be more expensive than a simple Min statement where the limit is implied by the nature of a Min and doesn't require ordering? Can you comment on that?

Comment: But to fetch the minimum one the optimizer has to scan all the values anyway . So the plan should be similar @marquelv

Comment: @MarqueIV sure, the cost of evaluating a LIMIT (after first sorting the values) and the cost of a MIN() (which also requires inspecting all the values, even though only the MIN is "kept") are about the same in most cases. This comes down mainly to the fact that identifying **any extreme value** requires testing **every** value - there's no magic that can make it easier, and the final form of the sql syntax is somewhat less important. At the end of the day, you'll only know the "best" query by testing/analyzing various alternatives in *your* environment.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  It's not the cost of evaluating the LIMIT that I was referring to. It was the unneccesary cost of sorting those rows which won't ever be considered.  If you're checking a min, it's a 1-to-1 op.  Check it. If it's the min already, do nothing. If not, grab the other one.  Compare that to sorting all the records, which has to be done prior to being able to grab the limit. Each value can be inspected multiple times to determine order.  That was my point.

Comment: Each value can be inspected multiple times using Min as well, think about it, each value needs to be compares to the entire data in order to determine if its the minimum one.

Comment: @MarqueIV strictly speaking, you're right that a full sort requires less logical operations than just finding a single min, max, etc., but this difference is exceedingly small compared with other considerations, (e.g. "is the data required by the query already cached in memory vs. still on disk"). Moreover, the db optimizer is a huge blob of very efficient algorithms that are very effective at optimizing these types of low-level operations, so much so that it is usually considered an anti-practice to try and "overguide" the optimizer. Even so, feel free to test both and decide for yourself.

Comment: @sagi, that's an incorrect statement. If you have 100 rows, Min Max, etc will only make 99 checks.  With sorting, there can be several hundred if not thousands of checks as everything needs to be considered relative to everything else which isn't the case with min/max.  Make sense?

Comment: You might be right about the Min/Max, but you can trust the optimizer that it has efficient ways of ordering rows as well, not even close to a 1000 checks. There shouldn't be any significant difference between them abs the Min won't necessarily be faster. Thats being said, you should always compare them yourself in order to find out

Answer (score 2):

A correlated sub-query can lookup the additional field you need.

```
SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    (
    SELECT MIN(lookup.EffectiveDate)
      FROM yourTable   AS lookup
     WHERE lookup.EffectiveDate > yourTable.EffectiveDate
    )
FROM
    yourTable
```

***EDIT***

The notion of "has to run once per row" is a mis-understanding of how SQL generates the execution plan that actually runs.  The same can be said for joining one table to another, the join has to be run at-least once per row...  There is indeed a larger cost to a correlated sub-query, but with appropriate indexes it won't be "extemely high", and the functionality described does warrant it.

If you had ***another field*** that was guaranteed to be sequential, then it would be trivial, but ***do not*** try to re-use the existing Promo field for that additional purpose.

```
SELECT
    this.*,
    next.EffectiveEpoch
FROM
    yourTable    this
LEFT JOIN
    yourTable    next
        ON  next.sequential_id = this.sequential_id + 1
```

Comment: I like this (and your code is the most clear of all the answers), but aren't correlated subqueries inefficient because they run that select once per row of the outer select?  Is this really the only way to achieve this?

Comment: I've added an update of what I thought was the way to go. Mind commenting on that too?  If that solution isn't possible, then this will get the answer.  If it *is* possible and you put it in an answer (or update this one) I'll mark that one instead.

Comment: Actually the functionality he describes doesn't require a correlated query, it can be done with a join(See me answer). It's just the exact purpose of a correlated query so it's the first solution that comes to mind.

Comment: @sagi - Changed wording from "require" to "warrant" :)  As yes, the half-cartesian-product alternative does work, though may suffer on larger data-sets.

Comment: And now I 100% agree :)

Answer (score 0):

show this, use subquery

```
select
p.promo,
p.EffectiveDate as "Start",
(select n.EffectiveDate from table_promo n where n.EffectiveDate > 
p.EffectiveDate order by n.EffectiveDate limit 1) as "End"
from table_promo p
```

Comment: I don't follow your 'where' clause.  Are you missing an operator?